# Importing a vuejs component without npm install or webpack

Tags: vue.js, npm, unpkg, libman

I am trying to include this component in my project:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-auto-complete

The problem is I am not allowed to use npm install. We are not using npm or webpack on the project (something about a small footprint and minimizing dependencies) so all I have to work with is LibMan.

I found the component on unpkg using LibMan and "installed" it. However this only gave me two files: dist/build.js and build.js.map (I assume this is some webpack thing).

Unlike other components I got from unpkg, (which give me something like component.esm.js to work with) I am unable to import the component from the file:

```
import { Autocomplete } from "../../lib/vuejs-auto-complete/dist/build.js";
```

gives me

> SyntaxError: import not found: Autocomplete

I have tried the component in a side project, where I used npm install, and it worked fine.

How do I make it work in my scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You have to import Autocomplete as a default import like so:

`import Autocomplete from '../path/to/dist/build.js';`

or use node's `require()` function:

`const Autocomplete = require('../path/to/dist/build.js');`

Comment: import  Autocomplete  from "../../lib/vuejs-auto-complete/dist/build.js";
this gives me SyntaxError: import not found: default

Comment: @Shaggydog Are you transpiling your code down to es5?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I wasn't the one who set up the project, and as you can see I'm new to this whole frontend/javascript/packaging thing. How do I find out?

Comment: OK I have gone through the plumbing of the project, and I can now say with confidence that there is no transpiling going on, files just get served as they are to the browser.

Comment: @Shaggydog I am not 100% sure why you encounter this error - I just tried it myself and can load it without problems. You are adding the `type=module` attribute to your script tag? (Vue shouldn't even load if you don't)

Comment: This is in the index.html <script src="app/main.js" type="module" async></script> and main.js has the Vue instance in it. Vue works just fine on the whole.

Answer (score -2):

You have to import it like this:

```
import Autocomplete from "../../lib/vuejs-auto-complete/dist/build.js";
```

And then in components section:

```
components: {Autocomplete}
```